# Only recording motion using gaussian mixture models

Tags: matlab

I am using [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detecting-cars-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html?prodcode=VP&language=en) on Gaussian mixture models.

I have a video displaying moving cars, but it's on a street that isn't very busy.  A few cars go past every now and again, but the vast majority of the time there isn't any motion in the background. It gets pretty tedious watching nothing moving, so I would like to cut that time out. Is it possible to remove the still frames from the video, only leaving the motion frames? I guess it would essentially crop the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give uses a foreground detector. Still frame should not have foreground pixels detected. You can then choose to skip them when building a demo video of your results.

You can build your new video by creating a rule of the type if N frames in a row do not contain foreground, do not write these frames in the output video.

This is just an idea...